# Child Objects Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have some JSON being parsed in via jQuery and loaded into an object `$framework`. I can call `console.log($framework)` and it returns this:

```
    Object 
    List item
    currentPage: Object 
    hash: "" 
    path: "/" 
    routes: Array[3] 
    url: "http://example.com.dev/"
    __proto__: Object
```

I can do `console.log($framework.path)`, for example, but `console.log($framework.currentPage)` or `console.log($framework.routes)` always return undefined. And in console I can actually expand both and see their child attributes, so it does seem that they're present. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: As requested, here's the JSON I'm working with for the routes attribute:

```
    {
    "routes": [
    {
        "title": "Root",
        "path": "/",
        "path_plain": "",
        "partial": "index",
        "container": "#main_content"
    },
    {
        "title": "Content",
        "path": "/content",
        "path_plain": "content",
        "partial": "content/index",
        "container": "#main_content"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dashboard",
        "path": "/dashboard",
        "path_plain": "dashboard",
        "partial": "dashboard/index",
        "container": "#main_content"
    }
]
```

}

EDIT: After working through this a bit further, it turns out the real culprit was a custom callback that was happening before $framework was completely set. I can't explain why I could see the objects in console before AND after referencing attributes directly and still got undefined, but at least it's solved.

Comment: Note that `console.log` shows the *current state* of the object, so if you change it later, that might be it. If you run `console.log($framework.routes)` in your JS console (not in script), what do you get?

Comment: Can you show the JSON as well?

Comment: add a screenshot on your browser or explain more, because it is impossible for an array to be undefined . it's a changement of state's object

Comment: @h2ooooooo That's a really interesting point. When I do that, it does log the values of the object, but then directly after returns undefined. But it does seem there's something odd going on with the timing, even though console.log($framework) and console.log($framework.currentPage) are being called at the same time.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi That's what I thought too. Here's a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/Ec1H The first set is console.log($framework), the second is where I call console.log($framework.currentPage)

Comment: @user2371898 I see the screen shot , can you write the line :5&6 in action.js?

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Here are 4 - 7:

`console.log($framework);`
`var routes = $framework;`
`var currentPage = $framework.routes;`
`console.log(currentPage);`

Comment: @Davidnbrooks I've made a quick example for you what happens with `console.log` and objects [**here**](http://screencast.com/t/rztt3g63vZ1U).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks a lot for that effort! Maybe I should clarify. When I'm creating $framework, I'm grabbing the JSON data as data and saying $framework.currentPage = data. So it's been defined other than just handwriting the object, and it's visible in console.log when I log $framework. I just can't access anything that would be a child element.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi I figured it out. I can't explain why things were being declared as undefined right after displaying, but it looks like it was a timing issue. The callback on my function was being returned after init, not when everything had been set. So while console logging $framework was showing correctly, it seems somehow I was getting a double loading of a variable scenario. It's fixed, but I'm not sure this one is so logical. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: if you use ajax , make your  request  AJAX make it synchronous : $.ajaxSetup({async:false});

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Thanks for the reminder. That part of the request was good, it was the function that called the request that called back too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `console.log($framework.routes[0])` to log the first item, `console.log($framework.routes[1])` for the second and so on if you are trying to see the content.

Based in your JSON, `$framework.routes[0].title` should return `Root`.